# How can I display total amount and also percentage value in Pie chart SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, pie-chart

The percentage value would be `Sum(Premium)/Sum(Forecast)`

This is what I have right now:
[image]
This is in Design Mode
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can change what shows in the data label for a pie chart in SSRS:

While in design mode, click on a data label in the pie chart. You just want to select one of them at this point.

In the Properties pane, look for a property named UseValueAsLabel; set the value to False.

Now, right-click on a data label in the pie chart, and choose Series Label Properties.

On the General sheet, there is an input for labeled *Label data:*. Enter an expression that will contain the values you want to display on the chart for that series. It can be a simple division expression that you can format to a percent on the Number sheet, or you can put other things in there too, as long as the expression is valid. What you enter here can be different for each Value you have on the chart.